# Index-time boosting using DIH with JdbcDataSource

Tags: solr

Is it possible to add boosts to docs and fields in Solr 1.4 DIH when using a JdbcDataSource? The documentation seem to suggest it's possible but I can't find any examples.

There are a few examples of how to add the boost="2.0" attribute to your docs/fields in XML imports, but how do you do the same with the JdbcDataSource?

The closest I could get to an answer was http://www.nabble.com/data-import-handler---going-deeper...-td20731715.html

Add a special value $fieldBoost. to the row map

Has this been implemented yet?

Answer (score 1):

$fieldBoost is not implemented, but $docBoost is.

[Source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/solr/trunk/contrib/dataimporthandler/src/main/java/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/DocBuilder.java?view=markup#l455).

[Special commands docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Special_Commands).

Comment: Hey Mauricio. Thank you for your reply! Much appreciated. Do you have some sample code showing how it's implemented? Or do you have a link to where it's been documented?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, If you want to change the score of the field or the document you have added
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents
just go through above link